# Drawing a Web Graph

Tags: asp.net, api, visualization, graph-theory

I'm trying to draw a graph on an ASP webpage. I'm hoping an API can be helpful, but so far I have not been able to find one.

The graph contains labeled nodes and unlabeled directional edges.
The ideal output would be something like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image:6n-graf.svg).

Anybody know of anything pre-built than can help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitely [graphviz](http://graphviz.org). The image on the wikipedia link you are pointing at was made in graphviz. From its description page the graph description file looked like this:

```
graph untitled {
    graph[bgcolor="transparent"];
    node [fontname="Bitstream Vera Sans", fontsize="22.00", shape=circle, style="bold,filled" fillcolor=white];
    edge [style=bold];
    1;2;3;4;5;6;
    6 -- 4 -- 5 -- 1 -- 2 -- 3 -- 4;
    2 -- 5;
}
```

If that code were saved into a file input.dot, the command they would have used to actually generate the graph would probably have been:

```
neato -Tsvg input.dot > graph.svg
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about ASP interface, but you may want to check out [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/).

/Allan

Answer (score 3):

We produce [mxGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/mxgraph.html), which supports ASP.NET, and most other mainstream server-side technologies. It's entirely JavaScript client-side, with just a thin layer to communicate written in .NET, so there isn't much ASP.NET required. But we do supply a ASP project for visual studio as one of the examples.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [zedgraph](http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page)

Answer (score 1):

GraphViz does a nice job for tiny graphs, but not for huge ones. If your graph is reasonlably large, try [aiSee](http://www.aisee.com/) or have a look at the alternatives on [this list](http://www.dmoz.org/Science/Math/Combinatorics/Software/Graph_Drawing/).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [QuickGraph](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/) to easily model the graph programatically, then export it to [GraphViz](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Visualization%20Using%20Graphviz&referringTitle=Documentation) or [GLEE](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Visualization%20Using%20Glee&referringTitle=Documentation), then render it to PNG.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here's another answer 2 years later. Protovis now does force-directed graph layouts rendered in browser:
http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/ex/force.html
Might be easier if you can't install client-side software. Also it's fun and interactive!

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to pull this off with [Google's Chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/).  It is very easy to get started with.

Comment: This is not an option for this type of graph.

Comment: charts and graphs are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I'm Image-Charts founder.*

If you are looking for an [web API](https://documentation.image-charts.com/graph-viz-charts/):

```
https://image-charts.com/chart
?cht=gv
&chl=graph g{1;2;3;4;5;6; 6 -- 4 -- 5 -- 1 -- 2 -- 3 -- 4; 2 -- 5;)
```

[image]