# free Graph Drawing SDK for ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, math, graph, drawing

I want to draw a mathematical graph in my asp.net web application. Is there any free control for doing this work?
I see http://www.yworks.com but it is not free.

Answer (score 2):

Following are the under Microsoft Public License (Ms-PL) license and
You might want to check out [QuickGraph](http://www.codeplex.com/quickgraph).

[NodeXL](http://www.codeplex.com/NodeXL) might also be of interest (visualization library). It's WPF, but you can use a container to host it if you need WinForms.

You can use check [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) to generate this sort of graph. My app generates the **.dot** file that can then is then passed into GraphViz. It supports a load of file formats, such as bmp, jpg, png, pdf, svg etc etc.

Reference:

[Open Source tools list](http://www.dmoz.org/Science/Math/Combinatorics/Software/Graph_Drawing/)
[C# graph drawing library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737771/c-sharp-graph-drawing-library)
[Drawing a Web Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69275/drawing-a-web-graph)

You could use [QuickGraph](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/) to easily model the graph programatically, then export it to [GraphViz](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Visualization%20Using%20Graphviz&referringTitle=Documentation) or [GLEE](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Visualization%20Using%20Glee&referringTitle=Documentation), then render it to PNG.

Comment: Can I use QuickGraph in web application?

Comment: not sure about Quick graph, GraphViz should work on web. check updated reference in answer..

Answer (score 1):

Under Eclipse open source license there is [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/)

It has many language bindings including C#.

Comment: It generates SVG or image files.